# Looking for a science fiction about an "outcast" assassin who falls in love with his target

Tags: story-identification, science-fiction-genre

I read this 3 years ago. It was about a chosen assassin that has the power to just "not exist" or either become invisible. You can share this power if you touch someone else. I'm not exactly sure of the power.

There's a girl with toxic parents who are pretty neglectful but like nice? She feels lonely so she's attracted when the assasin tries to kill her immediately. The assasin is confused of what he is feeling because that's not what assasins  do. Later on, the two accept eachother.

This makes the assasin a threat to either his organization or another company.
I also remember this book involving some kind of vial that enhances your power or something. The couple has to figure out a way to save the last vial and to prevent it from getting into the wrong hands. They meet some other kids along the way, including a child who has been used for the benefit of the organization (along with other kids) I think?

Later, they basically raise the kids they saved. That's all I remember.

Comment: Was this book set in the future?  Was there advanced tech or space travel?  Was the power to "not exist" more of a magical power or did it have a scientific rationale?  Was it set on Earth, for that matter?  Anything more you can give us would help.

Comment: @JohnHunt I think this was based in the future, it did not mention anything about space travel. His power ws more magical than scientific (though I'm not sure how he got it and why)  and everything was all set on earth.